# What exactly doest the lighthouse.userAgent mean?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am exploring the Google PageSpeed insights api and there in the response I see a tag called:

```
{
...
lighthouse.userAgent:'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/84.0.4147.140 Safari/537.36'
...
}
```

Docs mention userAgent="The user agent that was used to run this LHR."
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rest/v5/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed#LighthouseResultV5 What does that mean? How is this performance aggregated by running on all browsers?

PS: This is for Desktop version.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your second question, it makes no sense at the moment. Answered the main part of your question though.

Answer (score 0):

### What does that mean?

This lets you know what browser was used to run the test.

It is useful for if you believe that there is an issue with Lighthouse (a bug in your report) so you can test it directly on the same browser that Lighthouse uses.

There is also the "environment" object which contains how Lighthouse presented itself (it sent a header saying "treat me like this browser") to the website that was being tested. (`lighthouseResult.environment.networkUserAgent`)

This is useful so you can check your server isn't blocking requests for that user agent etc.

It is also useful for checking your server logs to see what requests Lighthouse made etc. etc.

See the [Wikipedia page for user agent for more info on user agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)

### How is this performance aggregated by running on all browsers?

As for your second question it doesn't quite make sense, but it has no impact on performance unless your server does something different for that user agent string if that is what you mean.